# Compare based on a mapping sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In sheet 1 I have these records.
[image: Sheet 1 where the data to be updated is]

Sheet 2 where the rules are
[image: Sheet 2 where the rules are]

I want to read the data in sheet 1 and match it with sheet 2 and then get the results from sheet 2 column C and put it in sheet 1.

Sheet 1 includes details column which contains a keyword. In this example the keyword is "residents" and the value in the debit column.

I want to check if the cells in first column in sheet 1 contains the keyword from sheet 2 first column and sheet 1 column 2 is equal to sheet 2 column 2 , then update sheet 1 with the value matching from sheet 2.

Comment: How many different key words are there and approximately how many rows on each sheet, less that 10 thousand ?

Comment: yes less than 10k , approximately 7 keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression to extract the key word and a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) as a lookup table to the description.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FillDescr()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Long, s As String
    Dim sWord As String, sAmount As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
   
    ' create word dictionary from sheet 2
    Dim dictWord As Object, dictDescr As Object
    Set dictWord = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictDescr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
    iLastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        sWord = UCase(Trim(ws2.Cells(i, "A")))
        sAmount = Trim(ws2.Cells(i, "B"))
        If sAmount <> "*" Then
            sAmount = Format(sAmount, "0.00")
        End If
        dictWord(sWord) = sAmount
        dictDescr(sWord & ";" & sAmount) = Trim(ws2.Cells(i, "C"))
    Next
   
    'Dim k
    'For Each k In dictWord.keys: Debug.Print k: Next
    'For Each k In dictDescr.keys: Debug.Print k: Next
   
    ' regular expresson to match words
    Dim Regex As Object, Match As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    
    ' join words with | to make pattern
    s = Join(dictWord.keys, "|")
    'Debug.Print s

    ' capture text between ()
    With Regex
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(" & s & ")"
    End With

    ' scan sheet 1
    iLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
    
        s = ws1.Cells(i, "B") ' text to search
        
        ' test for word match
        If Regex.test(s) Then
        
            Set Match = Regex.Execute(s)
            sWord = UCase(Match(0).submatches(0))
                      
            ' match all amounts if *
            If dictWord(sWord) = "*" Then
                sAmount = "*"
            Else
                sAmount = Format(ws1.Cells(i, "c"), "0.00")
            End If
            
            ' word;amount match in dictionary
            If dictDescr.exists(sWord & ";" & sAmount) Then
                ws1.Cells(i, "D") = dictDescr(sWord & ";" & sAmount)
                n = n + 1
            Else
                With ws1.Cells(i, "D")
                    .Value = "No match for " & sWord
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Yellow
                End With
            End If
        Else
            With ws1.Cells(i, "D")
                .Value = "No key word match"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Yellow
            End With
        End If
            
    Next
    MsgBox n & " rows matched", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: really appreciate it dear, it works perfectly 

Comment: can you add one condetion that if the amount in sheet 2 is set to "*" then ignore or dont match the amount and match only the word, because in some cases i have to match the word only without looking at the amount

Comment: that works but it's not what i meant, i want it to ignore the ammount matching and match the text only if sAmount = "*"   so if i put * in samount that means match the text only and dont look at the amount

Comment: so it should match the transaction no matter what the amount is if the amount is set to "*" in Samount             if the amount in Samount is a number match the number else if the amount in Samount is "*" match it as well :)

Comment: @kamal_ Do you mean that if sheet1 has a value it should be ignored if on sheet2 the key word value  = "*" ? . Like star means match all values.

Comment: @kamal_  OK try again